# REGEX behaves differently!

Tags: regex, pipe

When running the following

```
echo "abc>asf<tfg"|sed 's/.*>\(.*\)</\1/'
```

The output is:

> asftfg

I don't understand why `tfg` gets printed? My expected result is **asf**. Though, it works fine in the following.

```
expr `echo "abc>asf<tfg"`  : '.*>\(.*\)<'
```

Which gets me:

> asf

And help me to extract the string between `>` and `<` when input is being received from a pipe.

Comment: This question title could use some work.

Answer (score 2):

The `s` command in `sed` is a match-and-replace. In your case, `.*>\(.*\)<` is the pattern to be matched, and `\1` is the template to replace it with.

When you try to find a match for `.*>\(.*\)<` at the beginning of `abc>asf<tfg`, the result is `abc>asf<`. This part of the string is then replaced with `asf`. `tfg` was not matched, so nothing happens to it.

Using `.*>\(.*\)<.*` as your match pattern should get you the results you want.

Comment: You can also cheat with `awk` like this: `echo "abc>asf<tfg"|awk -F'<|>' '{print $2}'`